# Why is Sqlserver enlisting in transaction when Enlist=False?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Using entity Framework 5 (5.0.4) and a local SQL Server, why does the following code not create a row in the database?

Note that the connection string contains `Enlist=False`

```cs
using System;
using System.Transactions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EfTransaction
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var scope = new TransactionScope();
            var ctx = new MyDbContext();
            var eObj = new MyEntityObject { Name = "My New Object" };

            ctx.Set<MyEntityObject>().Add(eObj);
            
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            
            scope.Dispose();

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
    }
    
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MyEntityObject> MyObjects { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                "Server=.;Initial Catalog=MyDb;User Id=sa;Password=hunter2;Integrated Security=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Enlist=False;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntityObject>().HasKey(x => x.Name);
        }
    }
    
    public class MyEntityObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SqlConnection connection string parameter controls System.Transaction automatic enlistment by SqlConnection.  But EF Core *also* examines and enlists in the ambient transaction.

IE EF does not rely on the ADO.NET DbConnection to detect and enlist in ambient transactions.  You can supress the ambient Transaction with a nested TransactionScope:

```
using (var noTran = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
{
    using var db = new Db();
    //. . .
    noTran.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `scope.Complete();` to commit the transaction. Also, I strongly recommend a `using` block with `TransactionScope` and let that take care of disposal instead of invoking `Dispose` explicitly.

BTW, the `Enlist` connection string keyword controls detecting and enlisting in distributed transactions, not local ones.

Comment: Okay, I rechecked the documentation, it does state that setting enlist false will only opt out of distributed transactions. Is there a way to configure a dbcontext to not participate in local transactions short of creating a transaction scope with with the "suppress" option?

Comment: If your desire is to not use database transactions here, why use TransactionScope at all?

Comment: In my non-example code, I have a dbcontext which needs to be part of the transaction. It is performing some operations and at some point, it needs to fetch a good deal of data from the database. For performance reasons, I want to fetch this data using multiple database connections. I do this by creating dbcontexts across multiple threads (tasks actually). The newly spawned dbcontexts subscribes to the current transaction, causing it to become a distributed transaction, which is not supported.